# Регистрация COM объекта для использования его в 1С

Tags: c#, com

Вот так создаю COM объект :

```
namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    [Guid("6844AACB-9194-46bf-81AF-9DA73EE687DC")]
    internal interface IMyClass
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        //4. описываем методы которые можно будет вызывать из вне


        string GetTest();

    }

    [Guid("70DD7E62-7D82-4301-993C-B7D919430990"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    public interface IMyEvents
    {
    }

    [Guid("69EE0677-884A-4eeb-A3BD-D407844C0C70"), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IMyEvents))]
    public class MyClass : IMyClass //название нашего класса MyClass
    {

        public string GetTest()
        {

            return "fskdsklfdsdskl";
        }

    }
}
```

Регистрирую его на удаленном ПК где стоит 1С вот так :

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe C:\ClassLibrary2.dll /tlb
```

Видел пример регистрации вот такой :

```
C:\>regsvr32.exe C:\Users\my\source\repos\ClassLibrary2\ClassLibrary2\bin\Release\ClassLibrary2.dll
```

но он у меня почему то не работает, пишет отказано в доступе, хотя я полный админ.
Провели тест, установили студию на конечном пользователе ПК, где стоит 1С, создали проект в студии и поставили галочку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Все заработало! Как я понял из за волшебной галочки в студии. 
Вопрос, что я делаю не так, как мне передать dll с ком объектом другому пользователю и правильно его зарегистрировать?

Дополню, 1С выкидывает ошибку "класс не зарегистрирован", в случае если dll передана с моего компа, в случае когда компил со студии, все ок.

Сделал так:
C:\WINDOWS\system32>regsvr32 C:\Users\my\source\repos\ClassLibrary2\ClassLibrary2\bin\Release\ClassLibrary2.dll
Вот такая ошибка:
Модуль ClassLibrary2.dll загружен, но точка входа DllRegisterServer не найдена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regsvr32 регистрирует DLL особого формата; сборка написанная на C# без специальных усилий такой формат иметь не может. В частности, нужна та самая экспортируемая функция DllRegisterServer, а экспортируемых функций на C# не бывает.

Вариант регистрации через RegAsm - правильный (но я бы не стал класть ClassLibrary2.dll в корень диска; да и имя файлу нужно нормальное), но это вариант для сборки находящейся в GAC. Вам надо добавить опцию /codebase:

```
RegAsm.exe C:\ClassLibrary2.dll /tlb /codebase
```

Также убедитесь, что вы используете RegAsm правильной битности.

*Источник: [What does “Register for COM Interop” actually do?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3534693/4340086)*